# A take on custom ciphers

Tags: cipher, lateral-thinking, no-computers

There is something hidden in the text below. Can you find out what it is? Note: no computers or tedious work required.

```
bElZxmPVTwbElZxmPVTwbElZxmPVTwbElZxmPVTwbElZxmPVTwbElZxmPVTwbElZxmPVTwbElZxmPVTwbElZxmPVTwbElZxmPVTwbElZx
LgoQAHIKfeLgoQAHIKfeLgoQAHIKfeLgoQAHIKfeLgoQAHIKfeLgoQAHIKfeLgoQAHIKfeLgoQAHIKfeLgoQAHIKfeLgoQAHIKfeLgoQA
YtWsGNvyOqYtWsGNvyOqYtWsGNvyOqYtWsGNvyOqYtWsGNvyOqYtWsGNvyOqYtWsGNvyOqYtWsGNvyOqYtWsGNvyOqYtWsGNvyOqYtWsG
kUhraCjpBFkUhraCjpBFkUhraCjpBFkUhraCjpBFkUhraCjpBFkUhraCjpBFkUhraCjpBFkUhraCjpBFkUhjaCjpBFkUhjaCjpBFkUhja
zMXRJnDcdizMXRJnDcdizMXRJncddizMXRJncddizMXRJncddizMXRJncddizMXRJncddizMXRJncddizMXcddcddizMdcddcddizMdcd
SubElZxmPVSubElZxmPVSubElZmPVVSubElZmPVVSubElZmPVVSubElZmPVVSubElZmPVVSubElZmPVVSubmPVVPVVmPVVPVVPVVmPVVP
TwLgoQAHIKTwLgoQAHIKTwLgoQAIKTwwLgoQAIKTwwLgoQAIKTwwLgoQAIKTwwLgoQAIKTwwLgoQAIKTwwLAIKTwwLAIKTIKTwwLAIKTI
feYtWsGNvyfeYtWsGNvyfeYtWsGNyfeeYtWsGNyfeeYtWsGNyfeeYtWsGNyfeeYtWsGNyfeeYtWsGNyfeesGNyfeesGNyfeyfeesGNyfe
OqkUhraCjpOqkUhraCjpOqkUhraCpOqkkUhraCpOqkkUhraCpOqkkUhraCpOqkkUhraCpOqkkUhraCpOqhraCpOqhraCpOqhOqhraCpOq
BFzMXRJnDcBFzMXRJnDcBFzMXRJnDBFzMMXRJnDBFzMMXRJnDBFzMMXRJnDBFzMMXRJnDBFzMMXRJnDBFXRJnDBFXRJnDBFXBFXRJnDBF
diSubElZxmdiSubElZxmdiSubElZxmiSubbElZxmiSubbElZxmiSubbElZxmiSubbElZxmiSubbElZxmibElZxmibElZxmixmibElZxmi
PVTwLgoQAHPVTwLgoQAHPVTwLgoQAHPTLgogoQAHPTLgogoQAHPTLgogoQAHPgogoQAHPgogoQAHPgogoQAPgogoQAPgoogogoQAPgoog
IKfeYtWsGNIKfeYtWsGNIKfeYtWsGNIKYtWsGNINIKYtWsGNINIKWsGNINIKWsGNINIKWsGNINIKWsGNINIKWsGINIKKWsGsGINIKKWsG
vyOqkUhraCvyOqkUhraCvyOqkUhraCvyOqhraCvyOqhraCvyOqhraCvyOqhraCvyOqhraCvyOqhraCvyOqhraCvyOqhraCaCvyOqhraCa
jpBFzMXRJnjpBFzMXRJnjpBFzMXRJnjpBFzMXRjpBFzMXRjpBFzMXRjpBFzMXRjpBFzMXRjpBFzMXRjpBFzMXRjpBFzMzMXRjpBFzMzMX
DcdiSubElZDcdiSubElZDcdiSubElZDcdiSubElZDcdiSElZDcdiSElZDcdiSElZDcdiSElZDcdiSElZDcdiSElZDcdidiSElZDcdidiS
xmPVTwLgoQxmPVTwLgoQxmPVTwLgoQxmPVTwLgoQxmPVTgoQxmPVTgoQxmPVTgoQxmPVTgoQxmPVTgoQxmPVTgoQxmPmPVTgoQxmPmPVT
AHIKfeYtWsAHIKfeYtWsAHIKfeYtWsAHIKfeYtWsAHIKftWsAHIKftWsAHIKftWsAHIKftWsAHIKftWsAHIKftWsAHIHIKftWsAHIHIKf
GNvyOqkUhrGNvyOqkUhrGNvyOqkUhrGNvyOqkUhrGNvyOUhrGNvyOUhrGNvyOUhrGNvyOUhrGNvyOUhrGNvyOUhrGNGNvyOUhrGNGNvyO
aCjpBFzMXRaCjpBFzMXRaCjpBFzMXRaCjpBFzMXRaCjpBzMXRCjpBzMXRCjpBzMXRCjpBzMXRCjpBzMXRCjpBzMXRCRCjpBzMXRCRCjpB
JnDcdiSubEJnDcdiSubEJnDcdiSubEJnDcdiSubEJnDciSubEJnciSubEJnciSubEJnciSubEJnciSSbEJnciSSbEbEJnciSSbEbEJnci
lZxmPVTwLglZxmPVTwLglZxmPVTwLglZxmPVTwLglZxmVTwLglZxVTwLglZxVTVTwLglZxVTVTwLglxVTVwLglxVTVTVwLglxVTVTVwLg
oQAHIKfeYtoQAHIKfeYtoQAHIKfeYtoQAHIKfeYtoQAIKfeYtoQQAfeYtoQoQQAfeYtoQoQQAfeYtooQQAAfeooQQAQAAfeooQQAQAAfe
WsGNvyOqkUWsGNvyOqkUWsGNvyOqkUWsGNvyOqkUWsNvyOqkUUWsNvqkUUUUWsNvqkUUUUWsNvqkUUUWsNNvqkUWsNNNNvqkUWsNNNNvq
hraCjpBFzMhraCjpBFzMhraCjpBFzMhraCjpBFzMhrCjpBFzzMhrCjFzzMzMhrCjFzzMzMhrCjFzzMzhrCjjFzzMrCjjFjFzzMrCjjFjF
XRJnDcdiSuXRJnDcdiSuXRJnDcdiSuXRJnDcdiSuXRnDcdiiSuXRnDciSuXuXRnDciSuXuXRnDciSuXXRnDDciSuXXDDciSiSuXXDDciS
bElZxmPVTwbElZxmPVTwbElZxmPVTwbElZxmPVTwbEZxmmPVTwbEZxmVTwbEbEZxmVTwbEbEZxmVTwbEEZxmmVTwbEEZmVTwTwbEEZmVT
LgoQAHIKfeLgoQAHIKfeLgoQAHIKfeLgoQAHIKfeLgQAHIKKfeLgQAHIfeLgQgQAHIfeLgQgQAHIfeLgQQAHHIfeLgQQAHHIfeLgQQAHH
YtWsGNvyOqYtWsGNvyOqYtWsGNvyOqYtWsGNvyOqYtWGNvyyOqYtWGNvyqYtWGWGNvyqYtWGWGNvyqYtWWGNvvyqYtWWGNvvyqYtWWGNv
kUhraCjpBFkUhraCjpBFkUhraCjpBFkUhraCjpBFkUhraCjpBFkUhraCjpBFkUhraCjpBFkUhraCjpBFkUhraCjpBFkUhraCjpBFkUhra
zMXRJnDcdizMXRJnDcdizMXRJnDcdizMXRJnDcdizMXRJnDcdizMXRJnDcdizMXRJnDcdizMXRJnDcdizMXRJnDcdizMXRJnDcdizMXRJ
SubElZxmPVSubElZxmPVSubElZxmPVSubElZxmPVSubElZxmPVSubElZxmPVSubElZxmPVSubElZxmPVSubElZxmPVSubElZxmPVSubEl
```

Minor hint:

> The solution is hiding in plain sight.

Major hint:

> Monospace font is crucial.

Credit (and spoilers):

> Original idea created with https://www.kammerl.de/ascii/AsciiStereo.php.
>  Also, please forgive my complete lack of drawing talent XD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hated these images when they came up long time ago, because I couldn't see anything. Now, I tried again and I think I've seen ...

> a **cat**. Or at least something with four legs, a long tail and sharp ears. Drawn from the side, walking to the right.

I would be interested in learning if there is (apart from your eyes and your brain) a tool or procedure to detect these hidden images.

Comment: Can you provide a visual of how and what you see?

Comment: @Techidiot well, good question. That's why I asked how to extract it maybe via some software to illustrate what you are supposed to see. For me it was a "struggle" to see something. Check this rot13: uggcf://ra.jvxvcrqvn.bet/jvxv/Nhgbfgrerbtenz

Comment: Hmm.. Would be a nice tool to have. I get your point though. Thanks

Comment: I see it too - it is not easy though!